# Deleting variables on certain conditions

Tags: java

Is there a way to delete a variable from a string on a certain condition?
For example: there is two rows and each row has 100, 200, and 300 going vertical. 
If someone was to choose 100, how can I get it to delete the 100 but leave the 200 and 300..?

I have not yet tried anything but I have put the 100,200,etc etc, as variables and just printed out the variables in a certain styling to make it look vertical. The variables are int's too..

P.s this is for a jeopardy game.

Comment: Use a `List<YourData>` instead of a single `String` to handle, well, your data.

Comment: First question. Yes. It's computer science, you can do anything!

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza what do you mean? can you go further in details? i have all the numbers in system.out.println's... and there configured to make it look like they are vertical.

Comment: If you use a `List` instead of having N variables, then you can display them as you want and you can add elements as you please (same with items removal), but seems that you still don't even know how to work with arrays.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I do know how to work arrays..i have arrays in my program i just never knew of lists.

Comment: Then you can start reading here: [Trail: Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

Comment: @jason If you know about arrays, then why not have your questions in an array of strings, and use blanks to denote used questions?

Comment: @DennisMeng or even better, use a `YourData[]` array that overrides `toString` method to display it as you want/need instead of maintaining parallel arrays with the data you want/need

Comment: There are several ways to do this, but if this is for a Jeopardy game, I'd consider just using a two-dimensional array (you can make the elements boolean and set them to `true` once a question has been used, or make them some object containing your data and set the element to `null` after it's been used).

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question, it seems you have something like this in mind:

```
int c1_100=100, c1_200=200, c1_300=300, c2_100=100, c2_200=200, c3_300=300;
System.out.println(c1_100+"/t"+c2_100+"/t"+c1_200+"/n"+c2_200+"/t"+c1_300+"/t"+c2_300+"/t"+);
```

If you want to keep this structure, you could have strings instead:

```
String c1_100="100", c1_200="200", c1_300="300", c2_100="100", c2_200="200", c3_300="300";
```

and when the player selects the question c2_200 for example, you can do

```
c2_100="   ";
```

But this is not the best way to organize the code.
If you want to print out the data in a table-like form, you can use 2-dimensional arrays:

```
int questions[][]={{100, 200, 300}, {100, 200, 300}, {100, 200, 300}};
```

and then print them out in a loop:

```
for(int i=0, i<3; i++){
   for(int k=0; k<3; k++){
      if(question[k][i]>0){ //test if you assigned 0 to the chosen question
        System.out.print(question[k][i]+"/t");
      }
      System.out.println("/n");
   }
}
```

And everytime a user chooses a question, put 0 in it. For example, if he choose question in column 2 and value 100, do

```
questions[1][0]=0;
```

A better solution would be not to hard code the values, but use the position inside the array as a way to know the values:

```
boolean questions[][];
    questions=new boolean[5][3]; //here I created 5 columns and 3 rows
    //initialize
    for(int i=0; i<questions.length; i++){
           for(int k=0; k<questions[0].length; k++){
              questions[i][k]=true;
           }
    }

    //print
        for(int i=0; i<questions[0].length; i++){
               for(int k=0; k<questions.length; k++){
                  if(questions[k][i]){ //test if you assigned true to the chosen question
                    System.out.print(100*(i+1)+"\t");
                  } 
                  else{
                      System.out.print("   "+"\t");
                  }
               }
               System.out.println();
        }
```

and off course when a question is chosen:

```
questions[x][y]=false;
```

output:

```
100 100 100 100 100 
200 200 200 200 200 
300 300 300 300 300
```

And after

```
questions[1][1]=false;

100 100 100 100 100 
200     200 200 200 
300 300 300 300 300
```

Answer (score -1):

This answer assume you have a string that you want to print, and change pieces of the content.

Replace the variable with blanks.

First find the right position of the string you want to eliminate, using

```
indexOf(String str, int fromIndex),
```

Example

indexOf("100", x);

and for x you put the index of the column where you want to eliminate it from.
Then extract the substring from the beginning to the one you want to eliminate,

substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex);

and replace it into the original using:

```
replace(CharSequence target+"100", CharSequence replacement+"   ");
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html